# AlpineJS pass prefilled values to x-model

Tags: forms, model, field, alpine.js

I have a form which can receive dynamically value and I would like to pass this initially to x-model.

How can I achieve this? What are the best to goes in this case?

Hier is an example

```
  <input name="zip" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="{{__('PLZ, Ort', 'bdb')}}" value="{{$currentZip ?? ''}}"
               x-model="formData.zip">
```

`formData.zip` will be empty even if the value is filled `$currentZip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have an `x-init` directive on each input element, where you can set the optional dynamic value:

```
<input name="zip" 
       type="text" 
       autocomplete="off" 
       placeholder="{{__('PLZ, Ort', 'bdb')}}" 
       x-model="formData.zip"
       x-init="formData.zip = '{{$currentZip ?? ''}}'">
```